# (InvalidArgumentException) Action App\Http\Controllers\DestinationController@method not defined

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.3

I'm looking for helps.

I've been struggling with this over a day and I still didn't know what is wrong with my code.

I'm getting this kind of error

[image]

So, this is my **web.php** for the route that I wanted.

```
Route::get('/pramana/destination/{area}', function($area) {
   return redirect()->action('DestinationController@area', ['area' => $area]);
});
```

**DestinationController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Destination;
use Session;

class DestinationController extends Controller
{
    public function area() {
        $popup = 'popupsssssss';
        Session::set('popup', $popup);

        $destinations = Destination::all();
        return view('destination')->with('destinations',$destinations);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pass a parameter through url. Then later it would be like **destination/newyork**, or **destination/paris** and that page would showed up some contents of the spesific areas from the database on areas table.
I still don't write the code for that because I still got confused.

If I use the normal way of routing to a controller, It work fine but I can't get the params properly.

Am I doing this wrong?

I'm new at Laravel. And I'm sorry I'm not too good at english.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert this code to your model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'area';
}
```

then edit your code in web.php

```
Route::get('/pramana/destination/{area}','DestinationController@area');
```

finally edit function in your controller

```
public function area($area){
//use $area
}
```

Comment: This code works fine even without the model that you're recommend. Thanks dude.